# Extending github-highlight-selected chrome extension to every webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I found a chrome extension called github-highlight-selected at https://github.com/Nuclides/github-highlight-selected 
I am trying to extend this function to every webpages not just Github.
I thought it would be simply changing the manifest.json for
    `"matches": [ "https://github.com/*" ]` 
to 
    `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]`
However, the extension does not work outside of Github. Nothing is highlighted when text is selected.
Can anyone guide me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should know the previous extension is targeted at github source view, so the `hightlight-selected.js` contains many DOM operations which is bound to github source view, and will not be fit in other webpages, because their DOM info are not the same.

You should analyze the page you want to highlight, and summarize if there are the same part you can make use of.

Comment: I mistyped. I meant to say "I thought it would be simply changing the "matches": [ "https://github.com/*" ] to "matches": ["<all_urls>"]"
I have edited the post. Basically, it still doesn't work on every webpages when I changed to "matches": ["<all_urls>"]